# How to style polymer element dynamically

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to know if there's some way to style polymer element dynamically, for example :

**coba.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('hello-world')
class HelloWorld extends PolymerElement {
  HelloWorld.created() : super.created();
}
```

**coba.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="hello-world">
  <template>
    <div class="somediv">
      <h1>hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I want to style `.somediv`, but without using `<style>` tag. I tried querying it after `HelloWorld` instantiation.

```dart
HelloWorld.create() : super.create() {
  var el = querySelector('.somediv');

  el.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

But it does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to query on the [shadowRoot](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/polymer/PolymerElement.html#shadowRoot) :

```dart
HelloWorld.create() : super.create() {
  var el = shadowRoot.querySelector('.somediv');

  el.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: You could also assing an id to the element `<div id="someId">` and access it using `$['someId']`

Answer (score 1):

You could also assing an id to the element `<div id="someId">` and access it using `$['someId']` instead of using querySelector.

You should have got an error like

```
The null object does not have a getter 'style'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'style'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
```

but that error was probably swallowed due to a bug
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16372

Answer (score 0):

You was error when call shadowRoot in function created. You can use it in function enteredView().
My example code :

```
    void enteredView() {
       super.enteredView();            
         new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:10), () { 
        var el = shadowRoot.querySelector('.somediv');
        el.style.color = 'blue';
    });
}
```